# Unable to implement automatic logout react localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I am trying to logout the user in my react app automatically. I am receiving token from backend API that expires after 1 hour. I am storing the received token in my local storage as soon as the user login. My protected route '**DefaultLayout.js**' stores the logout function and is rendered after the user logs in successfully. Currently I am serving my app on localhost but I want to implement this functionality on production also. The problem I am facing:

Implementing automatic logout not working even after one hour of login session.

Here is my code snippets:

`DefaultLAyout.js`

```
class DefaultLayout extends Component {

  loading = () => <div className="animated fadeIn pt-1 text-center">Loading...</div>


  componentDidMount(){
    let userInfo = LocalData.getLocalData('currentUser', 'all');
    console.log(userInfo);

    if (userInfo.success === false && userInfo.message === 'Failed to authenticate user' && userInfo.responseStatus === 403){
      localStorage.clear();
      this.props.history.push('/login')
    }
    else if(userInfo.userToken === null){
      localStorage.clear();
      this.props.history.push('/login')
    } 
  }


  signOut(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    localStorage.clear();
    this.props.history.push('/login')
  }

  render() {
    //console.log(this.props)
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <AppHeader fixed>
          <Suspense fallback={this.loading()}>
            <DefaultHeader onLogout={e=>this.signOut(e)}/>
          </Suspense>
        </AppHeader>
        <div className="app-body">
          <AppSidebar fixed display="lg">
            <AppSidebarHeader />
            <AppSidebarForm />
            <Suspense>
              {LocalData.getLocalData("currentUser", 'isLogin') === true ? <AppSidebarNav navConfig={navigationProtected} {...this.props} router={router}/> : <AppSidebarNav navConfig={navigation} {...this.props} router={router}/>}

            </Suspense>
            <AppSidebarFooter />
            <AppSidebarMinimizer />
          </AppSidebar>
...... }
}
```

**Login.js**

```
class Login extends Component {
  // _isMounted = false;
  constructor(){
    super();

    this.state = {
      isLogged: false,
      email: '',
      password: '',
      isSuccess: true,
      isLoggedInSuccess: false,

    }   
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }


  loginUser = async (e) => {

      const { email, password} = this.state;

      e.preventDefault();

       await axios.post(GlobalVar.BASE_URL+'api/user/login', { email, password })
        .then(res => {
          const loginResponse = res;
          console.log(loginResponse);


            if(loginResponse.status === 200 && loginResponse.data.success === true){
              LocalData.setLocalData("currentUser", loginResponse);

                this.setState({
                  isLoggedInSuccess: true, 
                  isSuccess: res.data.success
                }, () => this.props.history.push('/'));  
            }

            else{
              const error = new Error('Invalid Login!');
                this.setState({
                  isLoggedInSuccess: false
                });   
                throw error;
            }

        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          this.setState({isLoggedInSuccess: false, isSuccess: false});
        });
  }
...}
```

**setLocalstorage.js**

```
export default function setLocalData(key, value) 
{
    var responseStatus = false;

    switch (key) 
    {
        case 'currentUser':

            const initialState = {
                isLogin: true,
                userToken: value.data.data,
                responseStatus: value.status,
                message: value.data.message,
                success: value.data.success
            };
            localStorage.setItem(key, btoa(JSON.stringify(initialState)));

            responseStatus = true;

            break;

        default:
            responseStatus = false;

            break;
    }

    return responseStatus;
}
```

**getLocalStorage.js**

```
export default function getLocalData(key, type='all')
{
    var responseObject = null;

    try 
    {   
        if(localStorage.getItem(key))
        {   
            var response;

                response = JSON.parse(atob(localStorage.getItem(key)));

            switch (type) 
            {
                case 'all':
                    responseObject = (response) ? response : null;

                    break;

                case 'isLogin':
                    responseObject = (response.isLogin);

                    break;

                case 'successMsg':
                    responseObject = (response.message);

                    break;

                case 'getToken':
                    responseObject = (response) ? response.userToken : null;

                    break;

                case 'getResponseStatus':
                    responseObject = (response) ? response.responseStatus : null;

                    break;

                case 'getSuccessStatus':
                    responseObject = (response) ? response.success : false;

                    break;

                case 'getFormData':
                    responseObject = (response) ? response : null;
                    break;

                default:
                    responseObject = null;

                    break;
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (e) 
    {
        responseObject = null;
    }

    return responseObject;
}
```

**Data response from LocalStorage**(consoled in DefaultLayout.js)

```
{
  isLogin: true
  message: "User successfully logged in"
  responseStatus: 200
  success: true
  userToken: "eyJhbGciOiJ..."
  __proto__: Object
}
```

I have tried lots of workaround but nothing seems to solve my problem. Kindly help out this soon.

Comment: How do you want to implement automatic logout By clicking in a Button that you will be redirected to another page?

Comment: I want both. On clicking the button logout as well as the automatic logout after one hour of logging by the user. In both the cases, it should redirect to Login page. On button click is working fine, but I am facing issue for automatic one.

Answer (score 1):

//you can implement auto-logout by the following code

```
let hours = 1;
let saved = localStorage.getItem(....);
if (saved && (new Date().getTime() - saved > hours * 60 * 60 * 1000)) {
  localStorage.clear()
}
// Increase expiration time after save
localStorage.setItem('saved', new Date().getTime())
```

// you can check logout status while making any call, if its more than an hour you can clear localstorage & redirect

Comment: So I need to check the logout status in my every component making API request? Is there any way to set up some middleware for the same ?

Comment: yes, or else you can maintain the last API call status at the backend.